# Alembic autogenerates empty Flask-SQLAlchemy migrations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using Alembic to handle migrations for Flask. `alembic revision --autogenerate` should, in theory, autogenerate a migration based on changes in my database. However, Alembic is simply generating a blank migration with the above command.

There's a [question very similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660676/alembic-autogenerate-producing-empty-migration), where the issue was that the proper models weren't being imported. However, I have imported the models from my Flask app, as shown in `env.py`:

```
...
# import settings from Flask
alembic_config = config.get_section(config.config_ini_section)
from start import app
from models import User, Item, Recipient # models are imported here from models.py
alembic_config['sqlalchemy.url'] = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']

engine = engine_from_config(
            alembic_config, # config.get_section(config.config_ini_section)
            prefix='sqlalchemy.',
            poolclass=pool.NullPool)
...
```

As well as imported db metadata in `env.py` ('start' is the name of my Flask app's main file):

```
...
from start import db
target_metadata = db.metadata
...
```

Running `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "initial_rev"` then generates an empty migration, although my Flask app would beg to differ:

```
"""initial_rev

Revision ID: 45296fd29540
Revises: None
Create Date: 2013-06-19 17:32:38.392268

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '45296fd29540'
down_revision = None

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    ### end Alembic commands ###
```

## Edit

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/autibyte/5826111) that shows the file structure for my app, as well as some additional code. It seems the issue is that Alembic does not like having the db imported from `database.py` without being initialized first in `__init__.py`. However, this is not possible *when blueprints are used* (because of cyclical imports), explained in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695045/353878.

So the question is, how can Alembic be used when Flask blueprints are used as well?

## Edit #2

I even tried printing `db.metadata.sorted_tables`, to make sure the database metadata was being imported correctly. Sure enough, the whole database schema was piped to the terminal. So why is Alembic generating blank upgrade/downgrade functions?

## Edit #3

I've concluded that the issue has something to do with the differences of `db.init_app(app)` and `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`, but I'm not quite sure what is causing the issue. To test this theory, I replaced `from database import db` in `env.py` to be `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`. Probably a bad idea, but I wanted to see what would happen for debugging purposes.

Alembic autogenerated and filled the upgrade() and downgrade() methods- except they were reversed! `upgrade()` dropped all three of my tables, while `downgrade()` created them with all the proper columns and metadata. I have no idea why this is, but I hope it is helpful to people trying to figure out this problem.

Comment: How has your schema changed when you ran `alembic revision --autogenerate`?

Comment: I have added three tables with several columns.

Comment: you have to import models in `env.py` so that they register into metadata.

Comment: @iElectric Thanks- but as you can see in the code above, I did import the models in `env.py`.

Comment: Is it possible you're running into https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/82?  Try adding:

    db.app = app


after the init_app call.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for responding- I tried adding db.app = app, but I'm still seeing empty upgrade/downgrade methods. I don't think that would affect alembic, since that's in `start.py`, while `db` is imported from `database.py`.

Comment: I just tried putting that in `env.py`, but it still didn't work. I'm not sure what the missing component is, since `db.metadata.sorted_tables` is correct when I print it in `env.py`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is how I use Alembic with Flask and blueprints.

https://github.com/davidism/basic_flask

I use the application factory pattern and call `db.init_app` within that.  After `db = SQLAlchemy()` I import all models that will subclass `db.Model` so that `db.metadata` is aware of them; note this is not done in the `create_app` factory, but just inline during module init.

When running `alembic`, the project folder is not included in `sys.path` so I set that up.  Then I create an app from the factory and set `sqlalchemy.url` from its configuration.  Also, I import `db` and set `target_metadata = db.metadata`.

This setup works for me all the time, no matter the project structure.  I included a very basic set of user models and a very dumb view in a subpackage with a blueprint.  Just make sure to load the relavent models in `load_models`, import the views after defining the blueprint, and import the blueprints in `init_views`.